# Can't access index of a tuple. IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

I created a db with sqlite3 in python, I then added a table with 5 parameters. I added an entry to the table filling all 5 parameters. I'm trying to select all entries with a specific parameter 'user'.

If I print the selected tuple without an index, it returns a tuple with 5 parameters **as expected**.

If I print the tuple with an index of [0], it return a tuple with 5 parameters **instead of the first  parameter only.**

If I print the entry with an index of higher than [0], for example [1], it returns **IndexError: list index out of range.**

I would like to access all of the indexes, but I don't know how to do it other than how I tried.

Code below: (financedb is my other .py file that contains a function `db_connect()` connecting to the database. I included that function in the code below so that the code is easier to replicate.)

```
import sqlite3
import financedb as fdb

user_name_input = input('Username: ')


def check_the_balance():

    fdb.db_connect() # Establishes connection to DB

    fdb.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE user=?', [user_name_input])
    check = fdb.cursor.fetchall()
    print(check[0])

def db_connect():

    global connection 
    global cursor 

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    command = f'CREATE TABLE test(id integer, user text, password text, montly_income real, monthly_debt real)'

    try:
        cursor.execute(command)

    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        pass

    finally:
        connection.commit()
check_the_balance()
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns something, ie there are records where `user` is equal to parameter `user_name_input`?

Comment: @GMB Simple answer - yes. Longer answer - after `user_name_input` if I query a user that is in the database I receive the entire row of 5 parameters assigned to that user. That includes specific ID, User, Password and two other FLOATS.

Comment: A good practice is to explicitly write the fields you want to select (even all of them, if that's the case). This will enforce the order and prevent your code to break if you move a column, add one in the middle or delete one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fetchall` returns a list of rows, so I would assume that you want `check[0][0]`? This may give you what you want:

```py
def check_the_balance():

    fdb.db_connect() # Establishes connection to DB

    fdb.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE user=?', [user_name_input])
    for items in fdb.cursor.fetchall():
        print(items)
        print(items[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed solves the problem! So if I understand correctly when you mention `check[0][0]` the first [0] refers to the index of which list of rows I would like to access and the second [0] refers to the items within that.

Comment: `check` is a list of rows, `check[0]` is the first row, `check[0][0]` the first element in the first row (i.e. the `id` of the first record returned by the query)

Comment: Yes, like `check[row][column]`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `fetchall` will return a list of rows, so `check[0]` represents the first row, of which the first element is the one you are looking for. It may also return an empty list though, I would check if its length is positive before accessing the first value

Comment: You are correct, it returns a list of rows. I was able to access the needed values with check[0][0]. Thank you!